# Issue with Docker expose port 8000

Tags: javascript, docker, networking, docker-compose, gatsby

I'm trying to Dockerize my GatsbyJS project so my friend can work on it without installing node.

The dockerfile builds fine and the server runs ok, the issue is i can't connect to the port exposed from Docker and i'm unsure why.

Error:

```
172.17.0.2 took too long to respond
```

-> for  172.17.0.2:8000

```
localhost refused to connect
```

-> for localhost:8000

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12.8
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
ADD src ./src
COPY g* ./ 
ADD static ./static
EXPOSE 8000
RUN npm run startvm
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3"
services:
  develop:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app/src
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
```

npm run startvm runs 
`gatsby develop --host 0.0.0.0`

But when i try the network url or localhost:8000 it does not work. I get can't connect to server

```
Local:            http://localhost:8000/
  On Your Network:  http://172.17.0.2:8000/
⠀
View GraphiQL, an in-browser IDE, to explore your site's data and schema
⠀
  Local:            http://localhost:8000/___graphql
  On Your Network:  http://172.17.0.2:8000/___graphql
```

Sadly none of these work, and i'm unsure how to debug further.

Comment: When you say "it does not work", what happens?  What's your host OS?  Why do you prefer installing and configuring Docker to installing Node?

Comment: Hey, i'm on a mac. 
It says: 172.17.0.2 took too long to respond for  172.17.0.2:8000
It also says: localhost refused to connect for localhost:8000

Well, my friend is hard in the head. He has node 14 installed, and my project doesn't work on that version and he refuses to downgrade. This is my only solution.